# how to split a data frame into multiple data frames using a conditional statement in R

Tags: r, split, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have data that looks like this:

```
time <- c(1:20)
temp <- c(2,3,4,5,6,2,3,4,5,6,2,3,4,5,6,2,3,4,5,6)
data <- data.frame(time,temp)
```

this is a very basic representation of my data.  If you plot this, you can see easily that there are 4 up-sloping groups of data.  I want to split the original data frame in to these 4 "subsets" so that I can run calculations on them, like "mean", "max", "min" and "std".  I'd like to use the split() but it will only split based on a factor level.  I'd like to be able to feed `split` a conditional statement, such as split if: `diff(data$temp) > -2`.

My problem is actually much more complex than this, but is there a function like `split` that will allow me to create new data frames based on a conditional statement?  as apposed to splitting based on factor levels.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 4):

The trick is to convert your conditional statement into something that can be construed as a factor. In this particular example:

```
tmp <- c(1,diff(data[[2]]))
#  [1]  1  1  1  1  1 -4  1  1  1  1 -4  1  1  1  1 -4  1  1  1  1
tmp2 <- tmp < 0
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# [13] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
tmp3 <- cumsum(tmp2)
#  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3
split(data, tmp3)
# $`0`
#   time temp
# 1    1    2
# 2    2    3
# 3    3    4
# 4    4    5
# 5    5    6
# 
# $`1`
#    time temp
# 6     6    2
# 7     7    3
# 8     8    4
# 9     9    5
# 10   10    6
# 
# $`2`
#    time temp
# 11   11    2
# 12   12    3
# 13   13    4
# 14   14    5
# 15   15    6
# 
# $`3`
#    time temp
# 16   16    2
# 17   17    3
# 18   18    4
# 19   19    5
# 20   20    6
```

Comment: Thanks, this may be a solution I can use.  As I said my data is much more complicated, but this gives me an idea of a possible way to treat it.

Comment: ok, thanks! Now can you tell me why when i try to do any operations on this list that your split() suggestion creates, I only get the first column returned (time in this example)??  I need to subset each piece, and when I do I only get the first column.  I tried turning each piece into a data frame with a for loop, thought maybe that would help and again, only the first column.  Do you know what is going on here, or have a suggestion for how to successfully track and preform operations on each piece??  Thanks!

Comment: @user1667477 Let's say you do `sp <- split(data, tmp3)`. Then you can access members of the list by something like `sp[[1]]`, and do operations over each list element with `lapply`. If you require further assistance, try posting another question that references this question and answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your data isn't so behaved, you can use `cut()` to create the categorical variable. The only 'problem' is that it's 100% manual.

```
time <- c(1:200)
temp <- (time %% 51) * (-1)^(time %/% 51) + rnorm(200)
data <- data.frame(time,temp) 

layout(matrix(c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,6), nrow=2))
plot(data, main='All data')

time2 <- cut(time, c(0, 50, 101, 152, 200))
plot(data, col=time2, main='All data, by time2')
data2 <- split(data, time2)

for (i in 1:4) {
 plot(data2[[i]], main=names(data2)[i])
}
```

EDIT:

Now a 100% automatic process:

```
time <- c(1:200)
temp <- (time %% 51) * (-1)^(time %/% 51) + rnorm(200)
data <- data.frame(time,temp) 

layout(matrix(c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,6), nrow=2))
plot(data, main='All data')


tol <- 10 # Here you set the minimum value to consider as a structural break
time2 <- cut(time, c(0, which(abs(diff(data$temp)) >= tol), max(time)), rigth=FALSE)

plot(data, col=time2, main='All data, by time2')
data2 <- split(data, time2)

for (i in 1:4) {
 plot(data2[[i]], main=names(data2)[i])
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks, but I need this to automated, there is way to much data to do this manually.

Comment: Ok, now it's 100% automatic.

Comment: Hey, thanks!  This may lead to something that will work, but for now I'm having trouble implementing this fix bc my time data is class: POSIXt and I'm getting an error when it tries to cut().  Do you know any way around this?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried many things and I keep getting error:  "Error in cut.POSIXt(), invalid specification of 'breaks'"  If you need more info to help me get around this, please let me know.  Thanks.

Comment: Using Blue Magister's idea, replace `time2 <- cut(time, c(0, which(abs(diff(data$temp)) >= tol), max(time)), rigth=FALSE)` with `time2 <- cumsum(c(0, abs(diff(data$temp)) >= tol))`